# React TypeScript with antd

Tags: reactjs, types, antd

this is my code

```
import { notification } from "antd";


const openNotificationWithIcon = (type: string, message: string, err: string) => {
    if(type == 'success' || type == 'warning')
        notification[type] = ({ message: message, description: err}) *//error here*
    return;
};

export default openNotificationWithIcon;
```

but it has an error at message

```
Type '{ message: string; description: string; }' is not assignable to type '((args: ArgsProps) => void) & ((args: ArgsProps) => void)'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'message' does not exist in type '((args: ArgsProps) => void) & ((args: ArgsProps) => void)'
```

I have seen in antd that message required ReactNode type and I fix but it not happend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the type of notificitaion['success' | 'warning'] is a function. This means that you need to call it instead of assigning.

So proper way to use it would be

```
 import { notification } from "antd";


 const openNotificationWithIcon = (type: string, message: string, err: string) => {
    if(type == 'success' || type == 'warning')
        notification[type]({ message: message, description: err});
    return;
};

export default openNotificationWithIcon;
```

Comment: thanks but why this bug happend when I add '=' can you explain it

Comment: Because you are trying to assign an object to a Function type
You cant do notification[type] = ({ message: message, description: err}) but instead try
notification[type] = ({ message: message, description: err}) => { //anything that you want to do here }

But still the proper way is just to call as I showed in the answer, since it is a function to be called. @PhươngTrần

Comment: @YunusEmre, could you take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963268/typing-react-props-returns-errors